# Autohotkey ctrl + Key == Arrow

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to remap the arrow keys to JKIL only when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is down using the [Autohotkey software](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

```
^i::Up
^k::Down
^j::Left
^l::Right
```

The problem is when <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> is pressed it sends <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> messing everything up.

What i want is (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> == <kbd>arrow</kbd>) NOT (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> == <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>), is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the updated version from [ahkscript.org](http://ahkscript.org)? It has a lot of bug fixes and added functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AutoHotkey v1.1+ from http://ahkscript.org

This works

```
^i::send {Up}
^k::send {Down}
^j::send {Left}
^l::send {Right}
```

Hope it helps